# Is there a correlation between month-of-submission to arXiv and citations?

Tags: publications, citations, arxiv, online-publication

The plot shows the number of submissions per month ([source](http://arxiv.org/stats/monthly_submissions)) on arXiv:

[image]

July and October seem to be the months with the highest number of papers submitted, and August the month with the lowest number, in average. I wonder if there is a correlation between the month of submission on the arXiv and citations gained, regardless from other factors.

I can speculate at least one reason why this correlation is possible.
I imagine that, for example, in August and December most of researchers (at least in Europe and Northern America) are on vacation, and therefore less people are following new submissions in these months. Perhaps this could result in a different rate of citation, just because papers submitted in this period have not gained a critical mass of "early" readers?

Is there a correlation between submission date and citations gained by a paper on the arXiv?

Comment: Related: http://arxiv.org/abs/0712.1037

Comment: Is there any variance information, or just means? Without variance, effect size can't be estimated, rendering speculation meaningless.

Comment: @jakebeal means and variance? I just plotted the total number of submissions per month. My question regards the correlation  between date and citations. Citations are not in the plot.

Comment: @sintetico Your question is predicated on the existence of a significant correlation: "Perhaps this [correlation] could result in a different rate of citation..."  If the correlation is not significant, then a) it undermines your speculation and b) you can delete the first 2/3 of the question.

Comment: The plot and my "speculation" just add context to the question. I am not asking if there is a correlation in the data shown. The plot shows the _submission_ rate. I speculate instead that a possible correlation between _citations_ and _submission_ rate can be caused by the different _access_ rate (following the mailing list) to the website. Causation implies correlation (of course the converse is not true). However I am not interested so much in the _causation_...

Comment: The variation in publication rate among months doesn't seem to be very large, so unless there is a very strong correlation you won't detect it.

Comment: @jakebeal: *If the correlation is not significant* – FWIW, the reasonable null hypothesis is that submissions are the events of a Poisson process. Then you do not need any further information to perform statistics. If it were not for multiple comparisons, you could just feed the numbers into the *C* or *E* test. As a quick estimate, the standard deviation of a Poisson process is the square root of the number of counts, which here is about 300 and thus far smaller than the differences between months. So, it’s safe to assume that this effect is significant.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft For a complex and coupled system like this, I don't think that's a safe assumption at all. For example, the totals might be highly affected by a small number of high-weight events like outages, policy changes, or high-salience external events.

Comment: @jakebeal: That may all be, but that doesn’t change the significance of the effect, just the cause, which it’s very difficult to say anything about in general.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I agree that we can reasonably rule out the hypothesis that submissions are a Poisson process. That doesn't say anything about the hypothesis that submission rates vary with respect to month. For that I'd want to do something like, say, slice up the dataset by years, so that we can see whether the distribution of "April" across years is significantly different from the distribution of "August" across years.